# Can I hunt for shiny Pikachu in the Safari Zone in Pokemon ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've been shiny hunting for Pikachu for 2 hours in the safari zone and no luck thus far - is it possible to get shiny Pokemon in the Safari Zone?

If so, what are the odds of a shiny Pikachu in the safari zone? Is there another place where I should be shiny hunting for Pikachu instead? I don't have a Pokemon with cute charm yet so can I still get it?

Answer (score 4):

The chance of encountering a shiny in the Safari Zone is the same as everywhere else in the game - 1 in 4096. When encountering Pokemon in the wild, this chance can be increased in two ways:

- The Shiny Charm (Key Item) triples the rate you can encounter shiny Pokemon (3/4096, or roughly 1/1365)
- Chaining (encountering the same Pokemon over and over) can boost the rate up to 40 times more (after 40 of the same encounters)

Pikachu appears in the South East region of the Safari Zone - if you try and encounter it elsewhere it won't appear.

You may also want to consider putting a Pokemon with [Static](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Static_(Ability)) at the front of the Party, rather than Cute Charm - Static will increase the chance of running into an Electric Pokemon, whereas Cute Charm only increases the chance of running into the opposite gender. Electrike, Voltorb, or (funnily enough) Pikachu all have the chance to have the Static ability normally.

#### References

- [IGN - Safari Zone](http://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/Safari_Zone)
- [Bulbapedia - Shiny Charm & affect on the chance rate](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Charm)